# Rails 5 -- "Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline, saas

While deploying on heroku a Rails 5 app, I have this error:

```
  remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
  remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
  remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
  remote:        rake aborted!
  remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...-weight: normal": expected "{", was ";"
  remote:        (sass):94
  remote:        /tmp/build_8b539749182a61fdc32fe1dcfad0fd07/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1278:in `expected'
  remote:        /tmp/build_8b539749182a61fdc32fe1dcfad0fd07/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1208:in `expected'
  remote:        /tmp/build_8b539749182a61fdc32fe1dcfad0fd07/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1203:in `tok!'
  remote:        /tmp/build_8b539749182a61fdc32fe1dcfad0fd07/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:677:in `block'
  remote:        /tmp/build_8b539749182a61fdc32fe1dcfad0fd07/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:747:in `declaration_or_ruleset'
  remote:        /tmp/build_8b539749182a61fdc32fe1dcfad0fd07/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:697:in `block_child'
  remote:        /tmp/build_8b539749182a61fdc32fe1dcfad0fd07/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:689:in `block_contents'
  remote:        /tmp/build_8b539749182a61fdc32fe1dcfad0fd07/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:225:in `directive_body'
  remote:        /tmp/build_8b539749182a61fdc32fe1dcfad0fd07/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:217:in `directive'
  remote:        /tmp/build_8b539749182a61fdc32fe1dcfad0fd07/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:696:in `block_child'
  remote:        /tmp/build_8b539749182a61fdc32fe1dcfad0fd07/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:689:in `block_contents'
  remote:        /tmp/build_8b539749182a61fdc32fe1dcfad0fd07/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sass-3.5.3/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:137:in `stylesheet'
```

How to fix it?

There're no "sass" files in my project, only "css".

A part of my Gemfile:

```
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 4.3"

group :assets do
  gem "sass-rails", "~> 5.0", ">= 5.0.7"
  gem "uglifier", "~> 3.2"
end
```

update:

```
.form-signin {
  max-width: 330px;  // Invalid CSS after "330px": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";" (Sass::SyntaxError)
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: What stylesheets are in your project? do you have any ui framework gems etc. What you have supplied here is not enough to go on

Comment: @engineersmnky, updated

Comment: `.scss` is `sass` (Sass 3 to be exact)  it literally means "**S**assy **CSS**" and you have an error in one of those files

Comment: @engineersmnky, typo. only css

Comment: Sass is a preparser and valid css is valid sass are you certain you don't have invalid css because clearly you do

Comment: @engineersmnky updated the error

Comment: That is not the same line the parser is complaining about do you happen to have a font-weight line about everything that?

Answer (score 0):

This error means there is some bad syntax in one of the stylesheets sources. Such kind of errors may come with the 3rd party stylesheets included in gems etc.

Try running `sass` with `-c` flag (I mean smth. like `sass -c app/assets/stylesheets/**/*.{c,sc,sa}ss`) to locate the problem...

Comment: oh, wait, actually I have only css files in "assets"